# Create X509Certificate2 object from client cert and key file in .net standard 2.1

Tags: c#, .net, ssl, .net-standard, client-certificates

.Net6 has a function [X509Certificate2.CreateFromPem](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.x509certificates.x509certificate2.createfrompem?view=net-6.0). What is the way to use client cert and key.pem file and create X509Certificate2 object in .Net Standard 2.1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

.NET Standard 2.1 is an unusual target, as it is essentially just the .NET Core development line (although Unity has updated their copy of .NET to be .NET Standard 2.1-compatible).  So the most common industry answer would be to avoid that target and just target a .NET Core / .NET 5+ version that meets your needs.

If you do want to target .NET Standard 2.1, though, you need to

- Load the certificate using either the `byte[]` (encoded contents) or `string` (filename) constructor, either of which understand the PEM format (but won't load the private key).

  - If you have the PEM contents as a string, you need to turn that into bytes via `Encoding.Utf8.GetBytes`
- Use the value of `cert.GetKeyAlgorithm()` to understand what algorithm the private key uses.  Call RSA.Create(), ECDsa.Create(), ECDiffieHellman.Create(), or DSA.Create() as appropriate.
- Load the PEM contents of the key file.
- Use the PEM header to know what data type the payload is.
- Base64-decode the PEM payload
- Send that decoded payload to ImportPkcs8PrivateKey, ImportRSAPrivateKey, or ImportECPrivateKey (as determined by the PEM header)
- Combine the cert and key with `X509Certificate2 combined = cert.CopyWithPrivateKey(key);`

https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/9e8d0a81a35f05eaa2c4d0ab258ed9a1f4e2ec76/src/libraries/System.Security.Cryptography/src/System/Security/Cryptography/X509Certificates/X509Certificate2.cs#L937-L963 may be a reasonable starting point... but a lot of its implementation uses things not available in .NET Standard 2.1.